# SQL Error: 904, SQLState: 42000 ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate, jdbc

Can below scenario of duplicate alias lead to an error when executed from JDBC or hibernate:

> SQL Error: 904, SQLState: 42000 ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

```
select * From table_master VW
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE(test_func(1, 300)) vw 
ON VW.table_key = vw.function_key
```

Facing this in production only. It works fine in test environment.

Comment: you're assigning the `vw` alias twice? That can't be right.

Comment: ya.. it works as oracle don't complain. But in production not sure why it gives error. Can some oracle schemas be case seneitive.

Comment: I agree that I can get the query to work in Oracle 12c myself (maybe production is on a different version of Oracle?).  But in my opinion, that should be the bug. I don't think the query should be considered valid, it's ambiguous.  If I were you, I would just assign 2 distinct aliases, which is really the only sane thing to do here, and try again with that.

Comment: What are the **exact** versions of the two servers ([edit] your question and add the  output of `select * from v$version`)

Comment: @sam_evang could you resolve it?

Answer (score 3):

In my case the DB field didn't exist, and it was returning 
SQL Error: 904, SQLState: 42000 ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

After Creating the field, of course it worked,

Double check those fields and make sure they are matching...

Hope it may give you a clue to find the issue

Answer (score 1):

In my case I missed `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)` on that `@JoinColumn`

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the user with which you are executing the query has the necessary grants for the test_func() function.